# Cannot find href on a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find the url for the trailer video from this page. https://www.binged.com/streaming-premiere-dates/black-monday/.

I checked the various properties of the `div class="wordkeeper-video"`, I cannot find it. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and play it. Then there will be something like this. The link is in `src` tag

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pzxGR6Q-7Mc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

PS: It is in `div class="wordkeeper-video"`

Answer (score 1):

The video `href` is not initially present there.
You need first to click on the play button (actually the image), after that the `href` is presented inside the `iframe` there.
The `iframe` is `.wordkeeper-video iframe`
So you have to switch to the `iframe` and then extract it's `src` attribute

Answer (score 1):

The full URL isn't there but all you need to build it is.

```
<div class="wordkeeper-video " data-type="youtube" data-embed="pzxGR6Q-7Mc" ...>
```

The `data-embed` attribute has what you need.

The URL is

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzxGR6Q-7Mc
                                ^ here's the data-embed value
```

You can get this by using

```
data_embed = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".wordkeeper-video").get_attribute("data-embed")
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data_embed
```